# Linkify - Text with "www." or just the domain at the end

Tags: javascript, regex

I currently have this as a function :

```
var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return inputText.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
```

So this work with the http in front, but I want it to work without http as well. For example:
"test test www.google.com test " or even "test google.com test"

Comment: there seems to be some debate in reliably checking a URL through regex. You might find an answer in here: http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/

Comment: Yep noticed Jorg, seems like a simple problem but it's actually really not!

Answer (score 1):

You can potentially match using www.* pattern but since now there is an unlimited number of top level domains it will be giving you lots of false positives

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var exp = /(\b(((https?|ftp|file):\/\/)?(www)?)?[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
return inputText.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
```

Of course, I think your RegExp should be completely redone, but using your strange logic, this may work for you.

Comment: everything becomes a link in my text with this, not valid sorry

Comment: Could you give me some clue how to redo this regex?